# Get Origin when request made internally instead of browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am making request from one web API to another.
I want that only first API can make request to second API, other should not allowed to do so.

I have applied CORS but as request came from API, there is no origin present in request.
Is there any way that my second API can only access by first.

NOTE: I'm using WEB API 2.

Comment: What did you allready try? Post some code

Comment: Is it possible to add an extra parameter to the call. If so, add a encrypted key. This will indicate who is sending the request.

Comment: Do you want to do this at a programmatic or infrastructure level? If programmatic, then requests will still make it to your origin and it is your applications responsibility to drop the request based on some criteria. At infrastructure level, you can apply the security at firewall and requests wont make it to your application code - but then you've got infrastructure to maintain, understand and automate.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.

[ip restrict](https://weblogs.asp.net/senthil/restrict-ip-address-in-asp-net-web-api) and [clientcerts](http://woloski.com/2012/08/04/securing-aspnet-webapi-with-clientcerts/) are two of them.

my favorite is clientcerts